# How is my server blocking webview wrapper?

Tags: linux, security, apache-2.4, web-server, android

I am running my php based website https://vegoplus.com on a self managed vps running Linux Ubuntu 20.xx and Apache. I built an Android webview app but the app only shows a blank page when loading my site. It will load all kinds of other websites, from Facebook to NIH.gov. So I don’t think it is my android code.

I was told that my site or server is blocking the ability to be embedded. How would I address this and what would I enable or disable? I was thinking maybe something in my htaccess?

Comment: I see nothing in the server headers that might cause this. Go do some [WebView debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) and see what is actually returned in the WebView.